# Transpose single column to array of unique rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a list of values that contain duplicates into unique rows.

| Column A |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 |

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 | Cell 2 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 3 |  |

I've tried using

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(A1:A3,TRUE,TRUE))
```

But any combination of the formula removes the duplicates and I want to maintain them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with MakeArray:

```
=LET(
    rng,A1:A8,
    u,UNIQUE(rng),
    MAKEARRAY(
        ROWS(u),
        MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A8,u)),
        LAMBDA(a,b,
            IF(COUNTIF(A1:A8,INDEX(SORTBY(u,COUNTIF(A1:A8,u),-1),a))>=b,
                INDEX(SORTBY(u,COUNTIF(A1:A8,u),-1),a),
                ""))))
```

[image]

This will expand automatically to any number.  It will also put the ones with the most duplicates at the top so it is an inverted pyramid:

[image]

Comment: Scott Craner is a steely-eyed missile man.

Comment: Thank you.. This was precisely what I was looking for. I am digging into every element here.. Great stuff!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,EXPAND(y,1,COUNTIF(A:A,y),y)))),1),"")
```

Or, with a build-in sort function:

```
=SORT(IFERROR(DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(TOCOL(A:A,1)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,EXPAND(y,1,COUNTIF(A:A,y),y)))),1),""),1)
```

Comment: JvdV is a steely-eyed missile man.