# How do I make rows that contain row headers into two columns

Tags: excel

I have a table that contact rows of data. The first cell in the row is a header for the row. I am trying to change the rows into two columns and maintaining the row header.

Table containing rows. In this example there are two. There could be more.

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row Header 1 | 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 |
| Row Header 2 | 90 | 23 | 45 | 67 |

End Result:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Row Header 1 | 12 |
| Row Header 1 | 34 |
| Row Header 1 | 56 |
| Row Header 1 | 78 |
| Row Header 2 | 90 |
| Row Header 2 | 23 |
| Row Header 2 | 45 |
| Row Header 2 | 67 |

I found an article here that goes from columns into rows, but U haven't had much luck reversing the effect. I'm not really familiar with its complexity. [Transpose single column to array of unique rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75166166/transpose-single-column-to-array-of-unique-rows/75169402#75169402)

This task is not resolved by using a pivot table as it is not the same layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Excel 365 current channel you can use this formula:

```
=LET(values,B1:E2,
headers,MAP(values,LAMBDA(v,INDEX(A1:A2,ROW(v)))),
HSTACK(TOCOL(headers),TOCOL(values)))
```

Via `MAP` the row headers are written to the same matrix as the values.
Then you can use `TOCOL` to make a single column of each matrix - merging them by `HSTACK`

[image]

Comment: Wow! Excel just amazes me, and equally amazing are experts like you who know all these techniques!

Comment: Wow. This is worked a treat!